# Keras: Store sequence values in RNN without using as inputs in the next layer

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I want to interpret an RNN by looking at the sequence-by-sequence values. It is possible to output these values with return_sequences. However, those values are then used as inputs into the next layer (e.g., a dense activation layer). I would like to output only the last value but record all values over the full sequence for interpretation. What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two models with the same layer, but in one of them you feed the Dense layer only with the last step of the RNN:

```
inputs = Input(inputShape)
outs = RNN(..., return_sequences=True)(inputs)

modelSequence = Model(inputs,outs)

#take only the last step
outs = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,-1])(outs)
outs = Dense(...)(outs)

modelSingle = Model(inputs,outs)
```

Use `modelSingle,fit(x_data,y_data)` to train as you've been doing normally.
Use `modelSequence.predict(x_data)` to see the results of the RNN without training.